# SmsManager android

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have a Main Activity class where i defined the pending intents and request codes and SmsManager. But when I run the app in the emulator in one it shows that the app doesn't have the permission to send sms and in another it shows only sms sent when the sms is sent and not when the sms is delivered.

```
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

The main activity class

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final String ACTION_SMS_SENT = "com.app.sms.SENT";
        public static final String ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED = "com.app.sms.DELIVERED";
        public static final int REQ_CODE_SENT = 10;
        public static final int REQ_CODE_DELIVERED = 20;

        Intent smsIntent;
        Intent deliveredIntent;

        PendingIntent piSent;
        PendingIntent piDelivered;

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

Defined all the intents and pending Intents

            smsIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT);
            deliveredIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED);

            piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,REQ_CODE_SENT,smsIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,REQ_CODE_DELIVERED,deliveredIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            final EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberInput);
            final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textInput);

            Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String numberText = number.getText().toString();
                    String message = text.getText().toString();

                }
            });
        }

        private void sendMsg(String numberText, String message) {

            sms.sendTextMessage(numberText,null,message,piSent,piDelivered);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

  //  And this is the SmsReceiver class that is to be called when the sms is sent by the application

    package com.example.angshuman.smsimplementation;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(MainActivity.ACTION_SMS_SENT)) {
                //code will run when the sms is sent

              if (intent.getAction().equals(MainActivity.REQ_CODE_SENT))
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Sms sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            if (intent.getAction().equals(MainActivity.ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED)) {
                //code will run when the sms is delivered

                if (intent.getAction().equals(MainActivity.REQ_CODE_DELIVERED))
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Sms delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

// This the android manifest file where the necessary permissions are declared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.angshuman.smsimplementation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.sms.SENT"/>
                <action android:name="com.app.sms.DELIVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

// And the logcat errors

```
02-16 22:22:05.004 17534-17534/com.example.angshuman.smsimplementation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.angshuman.smsimplementation, PID: 17534
                                                                                         java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10083 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:768)
                                                                                             at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:310)
                                                                                             at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:293)
                                                                                             at com.example.angshuman.smsimplementation.MainActivity.sendMsg(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                                                             at com.example.angshuman.smsimplementation.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                                             at com.example.angshuman.smsimplementation.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

//I don't understand what is wrong in the code.I'm trying to send an sms from one emulator to another by using it's pid but from one emulator the sms gets sent but only shows toast for sms sent not for delivered and in the other emulator the app just crashes

Answer (score 0):

You just add android premission : android.permission.SEND_SMS in the manifest file.

Comment: I already did. It's there in the manifest file. But it still shows the error.
Check my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what is wrong, but I did notice you do not try/catch when you send the message.  This code has always worked for me though.

```
    protected void sendSMSMessage(String phoneNo, String msg) {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```